# Selenium - When running builds via the grid, how do you get the console output?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We've been running Selenium tests via local RC for a few years, and are starting to migrate to the grid. We have been redirecting the console output of the server to our own test logs. It is quite useful for debugging. The console output looks suspiciously like Log4J - so it should be reconfigurable.

```
10:31:51.894 INFO - Command request: open[http://websiteundertest/IsSiteUpUp.aspx, ] on session 46c211b412474429957dbf6bebccd64d
10:31:55.323 INFO - Got result: OK on session 46c211b412474429957dbf6bebccd64d
10:31:56.330 INFO - Command request: isElementPresent[xpath=//h2, ] on session 46c211b412474429957dbf6bebccd64d
10:31:56.343 INFO - Got result: OK,true on session 46c211b412474429957dbf6bebccd64d
```

When re run via the hub, the console output appears only on the remote RC. The simple console redirection won't work. In scope of this question, we need to capture the remote console output someplace where the computer executing the test can get to it. We run our tests from a number of build agents via C#. We are trying grid 1 and 2. We intend to go directly to Grid 2.x.

Comment: You can't redirect the output to a local log file on the RC?

Answer (score 3):

What he meant was that this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register > mylog.txt
```

does not work. It will create a new file but it will be empty. I suggest using `-log mylog.txt`
argument when starting node or server to store log files

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Grid, you can redirect the output when you start each of your client nodes:
`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.15.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register > mylog.txt`

This is a Windows example. You can also centralize log files on some remote server by referencing a `\\serverName\mylog.txt` in your redirect.

When you say:

> The simple console redirection won't work...

I'm not sure I understand.